# Pre-select option matching db value without adding a new Select option

Tags: php, select, selected

I am creating a customer account page which displays the relevant information in the database and allows customers to edit their information.

The code below retrieves and displays the customer's account information from the database and pre-selects the values matching their information correctly. My problem is specific to Select elements - instead of selecting from amongst the existing select options it’s adding an extra select option with the value in the database, so that the value that’s in the database is displayed twice.

**Edit -** For example, if the db value for 'gift_privacy' is 'Standard', the Select options are being displayed as: *Standard, Standard, Gift ID Req, Not_Enrolled* instead of *Standard, Gift ID Req, Not_Enrolled*

How can I correct this code so that `selected="selected"` is applied to the existing options?

```
<?php   
try {  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
$stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$search = array('_', ',');
$replace = array(' ', ', ');
$rows = str_replace($search, $replace, $row);
?>
<select name="gift_privacy">
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $rows['gift_privacy']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['gift_privacy']; ?></option>
<option value="Standard">Standard</option>
<option value="Gift_ID_Req">Require program ID</option>
<option value="Not_Enrolled">Do not enroll</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... how is it showing twice?  What's the output of your shown code?

Comment: @Jon - If the db value for the code shown is 'Standard', the Select options are being displayed as: 'Standard, Standard, Gift ID Req, Not_Enrolled' instead of 'Standard, Gift ID Req, Not_Enrolled'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$gifts = array(
    "Standard" => "Standard",
    "Gift_ID_Req" => "Require Program ID",
    "Not_Enrolled" => "Do not Enroll");

$gift = $rows['gift_privacy'];
//$gift = "Gift_ID_Req";
foreach($gifts as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $gift) {
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

instead of:

```
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $rows['gift_privacy']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['gift_privacy']; ?></option>
<option value="Standard">Standard</option>
<option value="Gift_ID_Req">Require program ID</option>
<option value="Not_Enrolled">Do not enroll</option>
```

Of course, there are multiple ways to skin a cat, and you can check to see if `$rows['gift_privacy']` matches the current option on each line instead.

Comment: I inserted the code you suggested between '<select name="gift_privacy">' and '</select>', but that was causing it to always display the 1rst option ('Standard') instead of whatever the db value is.

Comment: instead of `$gift = $rows['gift_privacy'];` use `$gift = $row['gift_privacy'];`, we want it unedited.

Comment: That worked :-D Out of curiosity though, is there another way (like your suggestion of checking if $rows['gift_privacy'] matches the current option) that would be simpler to implement (since there are a few hundred select elements)?

Comment: It depends on what you have, compared to what would be easiest to implement. Checking each row would be more difficult if there are a few hundred, unless the checking of each one is done in a function. ^^

Comment: Any chance that you could help me with that? I'm using a similar function for styled checkboxes, but someone else wrote it and I'm not quite sure how to to modify it. 
$(function () {
              var selectColor = function () {
                  var select = !$(this).hasClass('ColorSelected');
                  $(this).toggleClass('ColorSelected', select)
                .find('.cbx').prop('checked', select);
                  return false; };
              $('tr.account_rows').on('click', '.Colorbox', selectColor);
          });

Comment: For that question, you should ask another question with it showing what you have and what you are trying to do.  The javascript you just put doesn't really relate. (let me know when you do, I'll look at it ^^)

Comment: Thanks to your input, I was able to get @Deep's code to work :-D I'm assuming that's probably an easier way to go than trying to create a function for all Select/MultiSelect elements?

Comment: It really depends on how many options you have.  If there's just a few, then that would work.  However, if you have a few hundred, a function would be simpler as you wouldn't have to do a conditional for each line of code, the function would be able to handle the creation of each `option` with minimal effort, and a lot less code. ^^

Comment: That would be really helpful :-) I'll share the link with you as soon as I post the new question :-)

Comment: I just posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14848744/1056713 and I included the function you wrote :-) I didn't bother including the code for the other function I'd mentioned since I realized that your code was much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . This is simple solution for your problem.

```
<select name="gift_privacy">
<option value="Standard" <?php if($rows['gift_privacy']=='Standard') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Standard</option>
<option value="Gift_ID_Req" <?php if($rows['gift_privacy']=='Gift_ID_Req') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Standard</option>
<option value="Not_Enrolled" <?php if($rows['gift_privacy']=='Not_Enrolled') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Standard</option>
</select>
```