# Function to check if the db value matches the current Select option

Tags: php, function, select, selected

I am creating a customer account page which displays the relevant information in the database and allows customers to edit their information. The code below retrieves and displays the customer's account information from the database and pre-selects the values matching their information, but since there are a few hundred select and/or multiselect elements I'd like to create a function which would check if the db value *(i.e. `$rows['gift_privacy']`)* matches the current option.

```
<?php   
try {  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
$stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
?>
<form action="account_information-exec.php" method="post">
<select name="gift_privacy">
    <option value="Standard" <?php if($row['gift_privacy']=='Standard') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Standard</option>
    <option value="Gift_ID_Req" <?php if($row['gift_privacy']=='Gift_ID_Req') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Require program ID</option>
    <option value="Not_Enrolled" <?php if($row['gift_privacy']=='Not_Enrolled') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Do not enroll</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Edit -** The code differs slightly for the multiselect elements. The element names are followed by square brackets *(i.e. `name="notifications[]"`)*, and values are inserted into the database as imploded arrays `implode(',', $_POST['notifications'])`. Those commas are then stripped from fetched values in order to properly compare them to the option's values `$row1 = str_replace(',', '', $row);`

*Existing Function*

This function applies `selected="selected"` to the correct options, but it's too cumbersome for me to use with so many elements and I'm not sure how to modify the code so that it could be easily applied to all the select and/or multiselect elements. Also, since the page currently uses standard select elements with hard-coded options I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require creating arrays for each element.

```
<select name="gift_privacy">
    <?php
    $gifts = array("Standard" => "Standard", "Gift_ID_Req" => "Require Program ID", "Not_Enrolled" => "Do not Enroll");
    $gift = $row['gift_privacy'];
    foreach($gifts as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $gift) {
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
    }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer :P?

Comment: @AmazingDreams - I take that as a compliment to what is hopefully a well-researched question ;-D

Comment: Do you have all the 'select' options in a database somewhere or similar? If not, I would suggest it with so many options, and then make your array to check against from pulling them from the DB.  It would simplify your entire project, especially if the select options are on multiple pages. ^^

Comment: @Jon: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear - each Select element only has a few options, but there are a few hundred Select elements on this page. The elements with all of their options have already been added to the page, so it would probably be simpler not to move it.

Comment: Ahh, ok, then I would agree with @Frhay, as well as the comment made on that answer in order to get it working 'cleanly'  Otherwise, you have to hard code each option as shown in your question and, overall, write more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem once and solved it by creating a function (or a class static method) to handle my option lists.

To print out your options you will have to cycle through them anyway, so while you cycle there is nothing bad in checking for each one if it must be the currently selected.

Just create a function like:

```
function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Giving `$dataArray` as your key/value options array, and `$currentSelection` as the key of the selected option.

So in your code you will have just calls to this function, like:

```
<select id='mySelect' name='mySelect'>
    <?php echo printSelectOptions($gifts, $gift); ?>
</select>
```

This should do the work!

EDIT: Adding sample to work with select multiple...

```
<?php
$options = array(   1   =>  "Test 1",
                    2   =>  "Test 2",
                    3   =>  "Test 3");

$selected = array(1, 3);

function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $selectionArray) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (in_array($key, $selectionArray) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}
?>

<select multiple>
    <?php echo printSelectOptions($options, $selected); ?>
</select>
```

The trick is passing the selected values as an array of keys, instead of a single key. In the sample I provided dummy arrays, but obviously you'll have to build yours from database... :)

EDIT: Select multi with arrays taken from the question...

```
<?php
$gifts = array("Standard" => "Standard", "Gift_ID_Req" => "Require Program ID", "Not_Enrolled" => "Do not Enroll");
$gift = array($row['gift_privacy']);

function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $selectionArray) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (in_array($key, $selectionArray) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}
?>

<select multiple>
    <?php echo printSelectOptions($gifts, $gift); ?>
</select>
```

EDIT: Explode multiple selected values

If you have mutliple selected values as a comma separated string, you just have to explode it before passing to the function I provided...

```
$selectedOptionsArray = explode(',', $selectedOptionsString);
```

So the ending code will look like...

```
<?php
$gifts = array("Standard" => "Standard", "Gift_ID_Req" => "Require Program ID", "Not_Enrolled" => "Do not Enroll");
$gift = explode(',', $row['gift_privacy']);

function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $selectionArray) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (in_array($key, $selectionArray) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}
?>

<select multiple>
    <?php echo printSelectOptions($gifts, $gift); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: That works :-D I'm not currently using arrays for Select elements though. Is there a way to use this function with standard select elements where the options are hard-coded?

Comment: Not cleanly... I suggest spending a little effort in making the key/value array first, after all you write down even less code that way, by not being forced to rewrite the option tags, which get handled by the printer function... :)

Comment: It'll take a few hours, but I think it'll probably make a few other components easier once it's done :-)

Comment: This seems to be working nicely for the select elements, but I'm having trouble using it with the multiselect elements (it stops pre-selecting values for multiselects when there is more than one value in the column). I'm assuming that some sort of foreach statement would work but I'm not quite sure how it would need to be structured :-( The code is slightly different for the multiselect elements (since they're treated as arrays), so I added that info above in case it would be helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer to add code working with select multiple... :)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the code for multiselects to work :-( Would you mind showing me an example using the array from the function I posted in the question?

Comment: I hope now it's more understandable... :)

Comment: That helped :-) It's working now, but it still has the same problem that it stops pre-selecting values when there is more than one value in the column :-(

Comment: I'm not certain to understand what "more than one value in the column" means in this case... can you show a sample of this case in your question so that I may be able to edit my answer as well?

Comment: My apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology. I meant that if more than one value has been selected. For example, the value of $row1['gift_privacy'] is "Standard, Gift_ID_Req" ($row1 is after the commas have been stripped from the fetched value so that it compares the correct values)

Comment: Oh that's clear now... you have multiple values in a comma separated string, instead of an array... just explode them... I edited my answer again... :)

Comment: That makes sense :-) Unfortunately I tried inserting the new line of code into the function without any success :-( I'm assuming that I'm just inserting it incorrectly, so would you mind showing me where to insert it?

Comment: If you look at the last block of code I already used the explode function in the right place in $gift = explode(',', $row['gift_privacy']) assuming $row['gift_privacy'] is your comma separated variable... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this to simplify it:

```
<?php
function renderOption($key, $value, $current) {
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '"' . ($key == $current ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $value. '</option>';
}
?>

<select name="gift_privacy">
    <?php
    $gifts = array("Standard" => "Standard", "Gift_ID_Req" => "Require Program ID", "Not_Enrolled" => "Do not Enroll");
    $gift = $row['gift_privacy'];
    foreach($gifts as $key => $value) 
        renderOption($key, $value, $gift);
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The 2nd line gave me an error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'", but I was able to get it to work by substituting it with the syntax @Frhay used. I'm not currently using arrays for Select elements though. Is there a way to use this function with standard select elements where the options are hard-coded?

Comment: I think he missed the third statement in the ternary if... editing... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use simpler method:

```
<?php
 echo '<option '.($key == $gift ? 'selected="selected" ' : '').'value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
?>
```

Edit: second option

```
 echo '<option '.selected_option($key, $gift).'value="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';

 function selected_option($val1, $val2){
  if($val1 == $val2){
   return 'selected="selected" ';
  }else{
   return '';
  }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this requires additional code declaring the function, etc. Would you mind including the rest of the code?

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with what you have, and this, or something very similar is the typical approach to this problem.

You would/could wrap it in an actual function, say `print_select( $array, $selected );` which would/could print out the entire `<select>` including the select themselves.

The final code might be:

```
print_select( $gifts, $selected_gift );
print_select( $colors, $selected_color );
// etc
```

Comment: The function that I included works, but as I explained, it's too cumbersome for me to use with so many elements and I'm therefore trying to create a function that would work with every Select element on the page